# Get earliest Date from Array of Dates

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Imagining if have got an array of Dates like so `var dates = [Date1, Date2, Date3]`. How do I get the earliest of those three date? I've tried several ways I found online, but none of them worked properly.

...and: how would I do that, if I had an array of a custom class 'reminder' with a property .fireDate, which means in that case: how would I get the object with the earliest .fireDate property?

I'm sorry I can't post any sample code, I'm posting this from my mobile phone ;-)

Answer (score 14):

`Date` conforms to the [`Comparable`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/comparable) protocol which means you can compare them with `<`, `==`, and `>`.  So you can use `min()` on the array to find the earliest.

```
let dates = [date1, date2, date3]
if let earliest = dates.min() {
    // use earliest date
}
```

If you had an array of `Reminder`s which have a `fireDate` property, you can pass a closure to `min` which compares two of your objects to decide the ordering:

```
let reminders = [reminder1, reminder2, reminder3]
if let earliest = reminders.min(by: { $0.fireDate < $1.fireDate }) {
    // use earliest reminder
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can add `Comparable` conformance to your `Reminder` class and then you could simply use `min()` as before:

```
extension Reminder: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Reminder, rhs: Reminder) -> Bool {
        return lhs.fireDate < rhs.fireDate
    }

    static func == (lhs: Reminder, rhs: Reminder) -> Bool {
        return lhs.fireDate == rhs.fireDate
    }
}

let reminders = [reminder1, reminder2, reminder3]
if let earliest = reminders.min() {
    // use earliest reminder
}
```